# How to bring an image in nib file to front of a subview

Tags: objective-c

I have a ViewController in which its nib file contains an image and I have subviewed a view to the ViewController.But the view hides the image.
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:myImageview];I tried this but its not working.Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already, show the document outline (from the menus, Editor->Show Document Outline). In the objects section, the positioning in the list is the positioning in the view (further down the list == closer to the front). Subviews are indented and listed under their superview.

Use this to make sure no views are covering the image. If this doesn't help, look at what views are added during run time.